# Refactoring design: abstract/interface/none?

Tags: java, optimization, interface, refactoring, abstract-class

First, have a look at my UI since it'll help you understand the problem:

[image: UI]

You'll understand that by selection one of the other, you end up with a set of similar actions with the same goal, but different implementations (`Sign in` and `Sign out`, for the most part). It is an `Android` project (thus written in `Java`).

The main class here is `AuthUI`. It sets up all the `onClickEventListeners` and the actions to be taken once the buttons are clicked. As it is, everything is contained within this single class, but my little pinky tells me that it might be a good idea to refactor the code so that I don't see the actual implementations of `GoogleSignIn` and `AcclimateSignIn` within that main class (which should act as a **Controler** more than the **Model**).

I've been thinking about setting up `AcclimateAuth` and `GoogleAuth` as separate classes within the same `Authentication` package as this `AuthUI` class. However, **I'm wondering what would be the best way to approach this problem**.

My initial thought was to try to declare both those 2 new classes as `abstract` and `extends` them in `AuthUI`, but then I remembered I could only extend one class. So secondly I went for the `Interface` approach, but decided to think a bit more before actually making a move.

My *current thought* is to have an Interface called `Auth` which would basically setup the methods `signIn` and `signOut`, and then two new `classes` (`AcclimateAuth` and `GoogleAuth`) would `implement` that Interface. The `AuthUI` would have access to both of those classes through having them as `private` attributes.

But considering I'll only ever have a single instance of those two new classes, maybe I should consider having their methods as `static`? Or would that be a poor design choice?

Hoping to get some clear answers on what would be a good refactoring technique in this situation. :)

Comment: Just because you have a single instance doesn't mean that their methods should be static. I would recommend the second option.

Comment: What is the downside to using `static` methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What I think

I would recommend The Interface Pattern.

## Why I think it

Not only does it fit your requirement pretty perfectly, You can specify an Auth Interface that makes sure each Implementation has at least some default methods (Example might be a Signin and Signout method by default). The other thing it lets you do besides have more implementations is you can inject the dependencies into your main `Controller` class contructor. This is really good for reusability since if I want to have a different implementation to say sign in with some other service, I can extend the interface and create my class. Without using interface pattern and contrustor injection I would have to change the main `Controller` class code and potentially introduce bugs.

## If you don't want to do it that way:

Best Case scenario for not doing it that way would be to have the `Controller` class select which sign in implementation it uses in its own code with ENUMS and a switch statement. For example, the button handler for your google button would set a "Sign in" ENUM to G or something and then youd have a switch case on the "Sign In" ENUM that would look for G and then run the code for Google's sign in implementation. This is fine as an interim but If you have alot of implementations it can get messy/unreadable plus it would introduce an O(n) time complexity with n "implemenations" and hence n switch cases just to find which implementation you were using. Constructor injection makes that O(1) because you immediately get the implementation you want. You could also set a configuration using a simple properties file. Something like: "SignInImpl=Google" as a line in a text file named "properties.config".
Then you can load this properties file with something like

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(YOURCLASSNAMEHERE.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

and then your SingInImpl Object can be made into whatever you need using reflection.

```
SignInImpl ImplYouWant = Class.forname(//put the property value here to find your class implementation).
```

Thats even better since you can specify implementation at runtime with a text file.

## On the Topic of static methods

If you only have one instance of these Classes and you don't want to have multiple objects floating around then by all means. It would increase readability and allow you to call methods more directly without the need for instantiation of Objects. It mostly depends on if you actually need multiple instances or not. Code is just an example, may contain syntax errors ect.

## The reason I wouldn't recommend Abstract class.

Abstract classes are better when you have alot of concrete subclasses/inheritance. Since there isn't much inheritance here its more of a Container relationship rather than an inheritance one. A good analogy might be modeling a zoo. If you want to model all the different types of animals you have, an interface would be better. If you wanted to describe how the animals were related to each other, abstract classes would be better. Your problem has different types of things as the root cause rather than the relation between those two or more things.

Comment: Interesting answer! Would you mind clarifying what you mean by `injection of constructors` and `injection of dependencies`?

Comment: an example of this would be if your `AuthUI` took in a `SignInImpl` Object as a constructor argument. It is demonstrated here [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection_comparison